# Different Minimum order quantity based on shipping zones in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I tried to set a minimum order quantity for the different shipping zones in WooCommerce, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

Here is my code:

```php
function check_min_order_amount( $packages ) {
    foreach ( $packages as $package ) {
        // find shipping zone
        $shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( $package );

        // find id
        $shipping_zone_id = $shipping_zone->get_id();

        // set min order per zone
        switch ( $shipping_zone_id ) {
            case 1:
                $min_order = 5; 
                break;
            case 9:
                $min_order = 15;
                break;
            case 8:
                $min_order = 15;
                break;
            case 6:
                $min_order = 10; 
                break;
            default:
                $min_order = 0; 
                break;
        }

        
        if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() < $min_order ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'La quantità minima d\'ordine per la tua zona di spedizione è %s.', $min_order ), 'error' );
        }
    }
} add_action( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'check_min_order_amount', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly, there are some mistakes in your code: Also you need to use a different hook, and to get the shipping zone ID you need to do it in a different way.

Here is your revised code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'check_min_order_amount' );
function check_min_order_amount( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $package = reset(WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages()); // get the first package
    $zone    = wc_get_shipping_zone($package); // Get the shipping zone
    $zone_id = $zone->get_id(); // Get the zone_id

    // set min order per zone
    switch ($zone_id) {
        case 1:
            $min_order = 5;
            break;
        case 9:
            $min_order = 15;
            break;
        case 8:
            $min_order = 15;
            break;
        case 6:
            $min_order = 10;
            break;
        default:
            $min_order = 0;
            break;
    }

    if ( $cart->get_cart_contents_count() < $min_order ) {
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( 
            __( "La quantità minima d'ordine per la tua zona di spedizione è %s." ), 
            $min_order 
        ), 'error');
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.